# Add Xamarin Forms BottomBarPage OnClick() listener

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, listener

I am using the `ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF` Nuget package to add a bottom tab bar to my application

[image]

```
        BottomBarPage bottomBar = new BottomBarPage
        {

        };

        var tab1 = new MainPage();
        var tab2 = new ReceivePage(null);
        var tab3 = new SendPage(false);
        var tab4 = new SendPage(false);
        var tab5 = new InfoPage(null);

        bottomBar.Children.Add(tab1);
        bottomBar.Children.Add(tab2);
        bottomBar.Children.Add(tab3);
        bottomBar.Children.Add(tab4);
        bottomBar.Children.Add(tab5);
```

How do I add a listener to this `BottomBarPage` which checks which of the tabs is currently selected, so that I can add the code below to this listener.

```
        if (bottomBar.SelectedItem == bottomBar.Children[3])
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout** to create a **tabLayout** object and create **Tab Item** elements nested inside a **Tab Layout** element in your XML.

You can use a **TabSelected** event on this object like so:

```
 tabLayout.TabSelected += OnTabSelected
```

Then you can write your OnTabSelected code.

Comment: Is there no cross platform solution?